# Reading files from a SFTP server once 10 files are generated using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am developing a project using Apache Camel Which transfers files from one server to another using SFTP. The SFTP component transfers one file at a time. My requirement is transfer 10 files from one server to another once all the 10 files are generated in the source server. Like if 9 files are generated in the source server, the files should not be transferred but only after one more file is generated. Can anyone please suggest me how to do this?

Below is my Route class

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
                .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                .redeliveryDelay(1000)
                .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

        from("direct:transferFile")
            .process(requestProcessor)
            .log("Input folder: ${exchangeProperty.inputEndpoint}")
            .log("Output folder: ${exchangeProperty.outputEndpoint}")
            .pollEnrich()
                .simple("${exchangeProperty.inputEndpoint}").timeout(0).aggregationStrategy(requestAggregator)
            .choice()
                .when(body().isNotNull())
                    .toD("${exchangeProperty.outputEndpoint}", true)
                .otherwise()
                    .log("Empty body, exiting")
                    .stop()
            .end();
    }
```

Comment: Are you wanting only to transmit the files when all ten are present, or must they only be read when all ten are present? What sort of interval will there be between the first and the last - seconds, minutes or hours?

Comment: I am trying to only transmit the files from one SFTP server to another, I will transmit the files 10 all at once or in a loop without a time interval in between.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Aggregate EIP](http://%20https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html). You could probably use the `GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy` with `completionSize` set to 10. Here is a good [article](https://blog.joshdreagan.com/2018/08/30/camel_aggregation_strategies/) to read about the subject.

I do not typically use Java DSL, so I have just combined some examples from Camel docs. Generally you should add to your route something like this

```
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
.aggregate(constant(true))
    .aggregationStrategy(new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
    .completionSize(10)
.split(body())
    .setHeader("CamelFileName", simple("${header.CamelSplitIndex}"))
    .to("file://some/directory")
```

Comment: Can you please send me a more concrete example? I was unable to do it in code.

Comment: do you use spring-xml to configure your camel routes?

Comment: No, I am using Java DSL. Basically I have a Spring Boot scheduler which is getting triggered at every 5 mins and it is invoking the camel route

Comment: Is this example for aggregating the contents of the 10 files together and place them in the destination directory? Actually I do not want to aggregate the contents, I want to transfer the 10 files as it is from one directory to another but only when 10 files are available in the source directory

Comment: it will place your files separately after they got aggregated